# Code Lab Exercise 5: SOAP Web Services

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, soap

I'm trying to do this example:
http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise5.html#section4

I have the entire code write in the appengine (both, server and client) but I have, in the tow projects, this error:
Project 'CodeLabEx5Client-Starter' is missing required library: '\Users\ravikumar\Desktop\suresh\gae\CodeLabEx5Part2\war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.xml.bind.jar'

Also, I don't know how to run the shell script that I've written in a file from terminal.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar error with GAE codelab exercise1. I solved it as below, Hope it might solve your errors as well.

1. Go to the 'Problems' tab in the eclipse debug console
2. Select the first error, Right click, Select quick fix

Comment: Yeah, I've tried something like that, but it's not enough...:(

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... described in the googcloudlabs:
"Download the jar required for xml from here"

But the link ( http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax.xml.bind-2.0.jar.zip ) isn't valid.

You can download it from http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.6/jaxb-api-2.2.6.jar

And... why are you tagging this question with 'android'? :)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, I've copied this file in the WEB-INF folder, but I don't know how to solve my problem...Oh! I've tagged with Android because most of times, I used Eclipse to do Android application...ups! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've made the 2.0 version of the .jar available [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7eNn0CRewQ8MWo2cU43ZzM5czQ/edit?usp=sharing).

You can add it to your Eclipse project by right clicking it and doing Build Path->Configure Build Path... -> Libraries tab. Then Add External Jar and point to this .jar file. Then switch to the Order and Export tab and check the box for this .jar.

It will let your project build properly. I still haven't gotten it to actually work as described though after hours of tweaking and fixing many other parts of this exercise.